# how to center (V,H) div inside div

Tags: css, html

My problem is that I wanted to have split page by two divs side by side (50% width). Inside of them I wanted to place another divs and make them aligned vertically and horizontally at the same time.
I think that it is possible to make it without JS, but I'm not able to do that.
Can anybody make my two circles placed in the center (V,H) of their parent DIV, which are 50% of width and 100% of height so that when I will resize my window the circles will always be in center (and side by side as is now)?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="kolo1">
        sometext1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="kolo2">
       sometext 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a JSFiddle for that:  [**http://jsfiddle.net/m5LCx/**](http://jsfiddle.net/m5LCx/)

Thanks in advance in solving my quest :)

Comment: Isn't this a typical CSS-related question? Not gonna write any code for you though, look into CSS yourself.
Also, looking at your code, it is not clear which circles are in which parent DIV.

Comment: google, first link : http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Comment: GregorPL, you are commenting on many correct answers, saying they are all working and what you need. If so, +1 them. The green checkmark should go to the best answer, which not only gives code but also explains why it is working. +1 rewards everyone who helped and gave correct answer, the green checkmark is for the best one.

Comment: @AndyM - I would love to but 'vote up requires 15 reputation', so I am unable to give +1 .

Comment: @Tynamo - thanks for Your search, but my problem was with div height:100%, not ...px. That is why I've placed my question :)

Comment: I didn't even look at your points, oops! Sorry!

Comment: There you go. Use your power wisely ;)

Comment: @AndyM - cool n.p. Solution that made my day was (apart from margins and top+left stuff) to make these divs respectively absolute->relative->absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give `postion: relative` to `.left` and `.right`.

and give below CSS for to `.kolo1` and `.kolo2`

```
 margin: -5em 0 0 -5em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m5LCx/13/)

Answer (score 4):

It's actually quite simple, all you need to do is to simulate a table-like behaviour:

1. HTML markup:

   ```
   <div id="container">
       <div> 
           <div class="half left">
               <div class="circle">hello</div>
           </div>
           <div class="half right">
               <div class="circle">world</div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. CSS styles:

   ```
   html, body {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
   }

   #container {
       display: table;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
   }

   #container > div {
       display: table-row;
   }

   .half {
       display: table-cell;
       width: 50%;

       text-align: center;
       vertical-align: middle;
   }

   .half.left {
       background: red;
   }

   .half.right {
       background: blue;
   }

   .circle {
       display: inline-block;
       padding: 50px;

       border-radius: 50%;
   }

   .half.left .circle {
       background: blue;
   }

   .half.right .circle {
       background: red;
   }
   ```

Final result http://jsfiddle.net/m5LCx/11/:

[image: result]

Comment: thanks for my eyes Crozin ! the colors you choose are wonderful :)

Answer (score 2):

**Working here http://jsfiddle.net/3KmbV/**

add `position: relative` in .left and .right class and than add `margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;` in `.kolo1` and `.kolo2` class. and remove top position from `.left` class

try it

```
body {
    background-color: #006666;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.left {
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 100%;
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #660066;
    position: relative;
}
.right {
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 100%;
    float: right;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #003366;
    position: relative;
}
.kolo1 {
    background-color: #0f0;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    border-radius: 5em;
    line-height: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.kolo2 {
    background-color: #00f;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    border-radius: 5em;
    line-height: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5LCx/7/). This one uses absolute positioning with negative margins to ensure the circles are always in the centre. CSS looks like this

```
.kolo1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5em; /* this must be half of the width */
  margin-top: -5em; /* this must be half of the height */
}
```

As @Tushar points out, you need to set the position of the parent element to relative also.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5LCx/5/)

```
.kolo1 {
background-color: #0f0;
width: 10em;
height: 10em;
border-radius: 5em;
line-height: 10em;
text-align: center;
margin: 50% auto 0 auto;
}

.kolo2 {
background-color: #00f;
width: 10em;
height: 10em;
border-radius: 5em;
line-height: 10em;
text-align: center;
margin: 50% auto 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: `so that when I will resize my window the circles will always be in center (and side by side as is now)?`   This wasn't solved.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not in the centering in VERTICAL.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `padding-top:50%` for parent `div`s (having class `left` and `right`)